# Como Agregar color select 2 Multiple

Tags: html, css, select2

estoy utilizando select2 Múltiple
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera pintar con un background-color la segunda y tercera opcion de un color diferente,
esto es lo que tengo `#select2-con_etiqueta-result-313r-Venta (Quiere Comprar- Cliente){ background-color: red; }`
pero no me pinta nada podría ayudarme
Esta es la parte de mi html

```
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--selectable" id="select2-con_etiqueta-result-313r-Venta (Quiere Comprar- Cliente)" role="option" data-select2-id="select2-data-select2-con_etiqueta-result-313r-Venta (Quiere Comprar- Cliente)" aria-selected="false">Venta (Quiere Comprar- Cliente)</li>
```

Ahí quisiera agregarle el color

[mi ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Reynaldo_123/wo6vqp31/6/) de como lo tengo actualmente.

Comment: Los **id** van sin espacios y tu quieres agregar esta coletilla con espacios incluidos al **id**: `(Quiere Comprar- Cliente)`.   Si se lo quitas tanto en el CSS como en en el elemento verás que te funciona bien.

Comment: El [estándar HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes:the-id-attribute-2) dice: _El valor del id no debe contener ningún [espacio en blanco ASCII](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-whitespace)_.

Comment: @masterguru  Acabo de actualizar la pregunta, adjunte como lo tengo actualmente, es que el html que me genera es automático con el select2 y quisiera agregarle un color a cada option de mi select